# A running program needs more space right now‼

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

I am using a program to import a Wikipedia dump to my local mysql server. The program is running. I start it four days ago. Unfortunately the drive C: is going to be full.
I have two HDDs connected to my PC. Each one are 80GB. The econd HDD is empty. How can prevent the program from throwing exception. It has no pause option. Is is possible to use second HDD in the scenario?

[image]

Comment: It is adding records to a mysql table?  Can you run a second script that exports records to the empty drive at txt sql statements, then deletes them from the table?  After that you can put the mysql data directory on a partition with enough space and import.

Comment: First you need to format the second drive.  You can't resize the first drive since it is actively in use.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know.  You would have to create you mklink to link the second hard drive to the first one inside of the mysql folder.  Mysql has a folder for each database. So make a new folder named "backup".

```
(assuming the new partition is D:)
make a folder called "mysql" on d:
```

(Your creating a junction to the second hard drive here.)

```
mklink c:\<location of the mysql database folder>\backup /J d:\mysql
create a new database called "backup"
create identical set of tables in the "backup database"

start moving records from the original tables to the "backup" database"
```

You need to break the data into groups such as by date(for example).  Then you can select all the data from a certain date, and insert into the new "backup" database and then delete the group from the original database afterwards.

If you are creating binary logs this could save some space.
PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE '2013-10-12 21:10:00';